# Connecting to metamask with react and Next.js not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, blockchain, smartcontracts, nft

I am following a guide to building an NFT marketplace with Next.js. I am stuck on the part for building a button that should open metamask. As far as I understand 'connectWallet('injected')' should open metamask, but for me, nothing happens. Not even an error message. What could be the issue here?

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Hero from '../components/Hero'
import { useWeb3 } from '@3rdweb/hooks'

const style = {
  wrapper: ``,
  walletConnectWrapper: `flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-screen w-screen bg-[#3b3d42] `,
  button: `border border-[#282b2f] bg-[#2081e2] p-[0.8rem] text-xl font-semibold rounded-lg cursor-pointer text-black`,
  details: `text-lg text-center text=[#282b2f] font-semibold mt-4`,
}

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const { address, connectWallet } = useWeb3()
  return (
    <div className={style.wrapper}>
      {address ? (
     <>
      <Header/>
     <Hero/>
     </>
     ) : (
       <div className={style.walletConnectWrapper}>
        <button
          className={style.button}
          onClick={() => connectWallet('injected')}
        > 
          Connect Wallet

        </button>
       </div>
     )}
   
    </div>
  
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not wrap the `_app.js`. Based on this [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@3rdweb/hooks)

```
import { ThirdwebWeb3Provider } from '@3rdweb/hooks'


const supportedChainIds = [1,4,137]
const connectors = {
  injected: {},
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ThirdwebWeb3Provider
      supportedChainIds={supportedChainIds}
      connectors={connectors}
    >
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThirdwebWeb3Provider>
  )
}
```